# DB2 Update statement

Tags: db2

I am very much new to DB2. I have a select query which I need to convert into update statement. query is something like this:

```
SELECT GUID,seq original_seq_no, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
FROM CHK_SEQ;
```

this select query works with MSSQl and Oracle but not sure with DB2. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you unable to test it?

Answer (score 0):

this select works with DB2 too. i.e.

```
WITH CHK_SEQ (GUID, seq, original_seq_no) AS (VALUES
  ('guid1', 100, 1001),
  ('guid2', 200, 1002),
  ('guid3', 300, 1003)
)
SELECT GUID,seq, original_seq_no, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
FROM CHK_SEQ;
```

How do you want to convert it into update statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple form

```
UPDATE (
   SELECT GUID,seq, ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
   FROM CHK_SEQ
) SET seq = new_seq_no
```